# Does Anaconda 4.0.2 already runs numpy on MKL

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have Ananconda4.0.2 in my system. I tried finding out my numpy config by following commands in python console:

```
import numpy as np
np.__config__.show()
```

It returned following output

```
lapack_opt_info:
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/include']
blas_opt_info:
libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread','mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/include']
blas_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/include']
mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
library_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['/home/<username>/anaconda2/include']
```

Does this mean that my numpy already uses mkl?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, starting with Anaconda 2.5 [MKL support is the default](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-25-release-now-mkl-optimizations).

To find out for sure, type:

```
conda search numpy
```

You will see things like

```
*  1.10.4                   py27_0  defaults        
   1.10.4             py27_nomkl_0  defaults        [nomkl]
```

or

```
.  1.10.4                   py35_0  defaults        
   1.10.4             py35_nomkl_0  defaults        [nomkl]
```

So the version without MKL is explicitly marked as such with `nomkl` and the ones installed (`*` or `.`) include MKL.

Comment: I am trying to install caffe which will require some BLAS implementation. I was wondering that since Ananconda4.0.2 by default provides MKL support for numpy and scipy, is it possible that i just link the existing MKL support to caffe installation instead of installing OpenBLAS as mentioned here https://github.com/tiangolo/caffe/blob/ubuntu-tutorial-b/docs/install_apt2.md

And if its possible please help me with the process?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like. As the [installation instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html)  say: `Set BLAS := mkl in Makefile.config`

Comment: this is useful info, thanks

Answer (score 2):

From numpy 1.15.0 OpenBLAS [seems to be the default](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#numpy-1-15-0-release-notes). I am on 1.16.2 and this holds:

```
In [2]:np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.16.2'

In [3]: np.__config__.show()
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/course2019/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/course2019/include']
    language = c
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/course2019/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/course2019/include']
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/course2019/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/home/tams00/anaconda3/envs/course2019/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```